Is every normalization a blowup?
I asked this at math.stackexchange, but received no reply.
Is the normalization of a variety always a blowup along some coherent ideal sheaf? If not, I would like to see a concrete counter-example.
Let $Y \to X$ be the normalization. The answer is positive in the following situations:

$X$ is quasi-projective. This follows since normalization is a projective birational morphism.
The singularities are mild, namely $X$ is Gorenstein and $Y$ is both Gorenstein and Cohen–Macaulay. In this case, by arXiv:1608.04525, normalization is the blowup along the conductor ideal.

By variety, I mean an integral separated scheme of finite type over the complex numbers.

It's true for  affine $X$ by what you said, so it's true locally for any $X$. Blow ups patch, so it's true for $X$.

@DonuArapura Using the local arguments that you suggest, the following result is proved in https://mathoverflow.net/a/53811: if $f\colon Z \to X$ is any projective birational morphism of varieties, then there exists a blowup $\pi$ such that $\pi$ factors through $f$.
But I do not see how to do the gluing to directly conclude that $f$ is a blowup.
